# Deducing topology from a function with no critical values.

Tags: algebraic-topology, morse-theory

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact manifold with a boundary. Let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function constant on each component of the boundary of $X$ (not sure if thats important). Assume that $f$ has no critical points on $X$.

1. Can I deduce from Morse inequites  that Euler's characteristics of $X$ is 0 ($\chi(X)=0$)? I'm not sure if Morse inequites are working if $X$ is a manifold with a boundary.
2. Can I extract any other topological information of $X$ (other betti numbers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume $X$ is connected.

Under your assumption that $f$ is constant on each component of $\partial X$, it follows that $X$ has a product structure of the form $X \approx Y \times [a,b]$ such that $f$ is projection onto the second factor. To be precise, there is a compact manifold $Y$ with empty boundary of dimension $n-1$, an interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$, and a homeomorphism $h : Y \times [a,b] \to X$, such that the composition $f \circ h : Y \times [a,b] \to X$ is simply the projection onto the second factor.

Here's an intuitive outline of the proof, which should be regarded as a simple exercise using the methods of Morse theory. Let $C_0$ be a component of $\partial X$ on which the minimal value of $f$ is achieved, and suppose that $f(C_0)=a$. Since $f$ has no critical point on $C_0$, there is a product structure $C_0 \times [a,a+\epsilon)$ on some neighborhood of $C_0$. One can now keep extending the product structure over more and more of $X$, constructing product structures $C_0 \times [a,a+s)$. There are only two things that can stop this growth. First, one can run into a critical value $s$. But there are no critical values. Second, one can run into another component $C_1$ of $\partial X$, with $f(x)=s$ for some $x \in C_1$. But then $f(C_1)=s$ and the proof is complete with $b=s$.

Comment: I rewrote my proof to accomodate your more restricted question.

Comment: Can i deduce from that $\chi (X)=0$ ? What about other betti numbers?

Comment: $X$ is homeomophic to $Y \times [a,b]$ and therefore is homotopy equivalent to $Y$, which can be any closed manifold whatsoever. So no, you cannot deduce a single thing about the homotopy type of $X$ other than that it is homotopy equivalent to a closed manifold of one dimension lower.

Comment: Are you sure? Doesn't Poincaré–Hopf theorem implies that $\chi(X)=0$? Look at the coments after the theory  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem. What does "pointing in the outward normal direction along the boundary" formally means?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. If you want to ask a detailed question about the Poincare-Hopf theorem and how to apply it, that might be a good fit for a new question. As it stands I'll say briefly: *If* you assume that a Riemannian metric is given on $M$ then the function $f$ has a gradient vector field which points inward on those components of $\partial M$ where $f$ has a local min, and points outward on those components of $\partial M$ where $f$ has a local max. So the Poincare-Hopf theorem will not apply.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you don't mind take a look at this question that i post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123900/critical-points-in-a-simple-case-of-manifold-with-boundary.