# Critical points in a simple case of manifold with boundary.

Tags: algebraic-topology, morse-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth, connected, compact manifold and $Y=X\times [a,b]$. Let $f:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Morse function on $Y$ such that $f|_{X\times \{a\}}=a$ and $f|_{X\times \{b\}}=b$. What can we say about critical points of $f$? I'm looking for a version of Morse inequalities or Poincare-Hopf theorem siutable for this situation.

Comment: One thing you can say topologically is that all the critical points have to "cancel". The Morse function will induce a handle decomposition of Y which computes the relative homology of $(Y, X\times \{a\})$, which vanishes. The precise way in which the handles "cancel" depends on the precise expression of the boundary operators.

Comment: "The precise way in which the handles "cancel" depends on the precise expression of the boundary operators" -could you elaborate more on this? You can assume for now that $X=\mathbb{S}^{n}$